# Delphi - check if element exists twice in TArray<string>

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have this code

```
var
arr: TArray<string>;
e1, e2, e3, e4: string;
begin

e1 := 'val1';
e2 := 'val2';
e3 := 'val3';
e4 := 'val4';

arr := TArray<string>.Create(e1, e2, e3, e4);
```

I need now to check if e1 to e4 exists in the above array **twice** what is the best way to do it ?
I should also skip checking any element have a null value.

also please advise if I should free this array manually

Thanks

Comment: Just as a note: You can simplify your entire code to `arr := TArray<string>.Create('val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4');`, without the separate variables being needed.

Comment: Forgot to ask, do you need to determine, if a certain string is in that array exactly, or at least twice ?

Comment: @TLama exact string exists twice in the array but I should skip the check with e1 is null

Comment: @KenWhite that because I am reading string from another source so I need to work with variables

Comment: @Welliam, 4 variables? 4 strings? That's it? Or is this just an example.

Comment: @Welliam, I see, but do you want to determine if a certain string value, e.g. `val2` is in that array exactly twice or it's sufficient for you to know if that value is in the array at least twice. That's important to know, because in the first case you'd have to search matches in the whole array (or collection as some people suggest), whilst in the second case you could exit the function immediately when you find at least two matches.

Comment: @TLama any duplicate should exit.......thanks

Comment: Many Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the fun of playing with algorithms; If the original array is large-enough to make the naive `O(n^2)` algorithm impractical, and since the OP is using a version of Delphi that has generics, I propose using an `TDictionary<string, integer>` to track all strings *without* sorting, and identify duplicates.

This would be efficient for a number of reasons:

- TDictionary offers constant-time inserts, it's almost `O(n)`. We know the size of the array from the beginning so we can use `TDictionary` without ever growing it. This makes the whole algorithm `O(n)`.
- Since the strings are already in an array, and Delphi strings are reference-counted, putting strings into the array isn't going to actually copy the string!
- With this algorithm the array is walked only once.

The code:

```
type
  TZeroWidthRecord = record
  end;

function FindFirstDuplicate(const ArrayOfString: array of string): Integer;
var Dict: TDictionary<string, TZeroWidthRecord>;
    i: Integer;
    ZW: TZeroWidthRecord;
begin
  Dict := TDictionary<string, TZeroWidthRecord>.Create(Length(ArrayOfString));
  try
    for i:=0 to High(ArrayOfString) do
      try
        Dict.Add(ArrayOfString[i], ZW);
      except on E:Exception do
        Exit(i);
      end;
  finally Dict.Free;
  end;
  // No duplicates found:
  Result := -1;
end;
```

---

To answer David's comment I made a short test program that compares this `TDictionary` based algorithm to the `sort-and-search` algorithm. I created random arrays of strings then tried finding the first duplicate. My arrays contain no duplicates, if there were duplicates then the run-time for the TDictionary would be proportional to the the average first-hit duplicate. If, for example, on average the TDictionary would find a duplicate in the middle of the array then the average runtime for the TDict algorithm would be half.  The sort-based algorithm needs to sort the whole array, and the sorting is what takes up the most time.

As always with sorting and dictionary based algorithms, one needs to test with *realistic* data. If, for example, I'd have tested with the short strings in the OP's questions, there would be no competition between TDict and sort: Dict would be faster even for trivial length arrays. But the moment the average string length increases, the sort based algorithm starts getting better; But then again, this depends on the strings: if, for example, most of the strings would share a long prefix then the "compare" stage in the sorting algorithm would take significantly longer, making TDictionary look better again!

### Test table 1, no duplicates

```
*==========*===========================*
|          | Number of strings         |
| Avg str  | in the Array for          |
| length   | TDictionary to be faster  |
*======================================*
| 7        | 33                        |
| 10       | 73                        |
| 13       | 73                        |
| 16       | 163                       |
| 19       | 163                       |
| 22       | 366                       |
| 25       | 366                       |
| 28       | 549                       |
| 37       | 2776                      |
| 40       | 2776                      |
| 43       | 2776                      |
| 46       | 4164                      |
| 49       | 9369                      |
| 52       | 9369                      |
| 55       | 9369                      |
| 58       | 21079                     |
*==========*===========================*
```

### Test table 2, duplicate at 1/2 of the array

This would be the results if the first duplicate is found exactly in the middle of the array. Notice the huge difference for the average string length 58:

```
*==========*===========================*
|          | Number of strings         |
| Avg str  | in the Array for          |
| length   | TDictionary to be faster  |
*======================================*
| 30       | 109                       |
| 33       | 163                       |
| 36       | 163                       |
| 58       | 366                       |
*==========*===========================*
```

### Test table 3, duplicate at 1/4

And this would happen if the first duplicate is found around 1/4 of the array:

```
*==========*===========================*
|          | Number of strings         |
| Avg str  | in the Array for          |
| length   | TDictionary to be faster  |
*======================================*
| 29       | 73                        |
| 32       | 73                        |
| 38       | 73                        |
| 57       | 109                       |
*==========*===========================*
```

Here's the test application: http://pastebin.com/vDznwKtZ

Comment: you mean `ContainsValue` as `ContainsKey` need an integer ?

Comment: @Welliam, `TDictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey` takes a parameter of type `TKey`; In our case `ContainsKey()` takes a `string` parameter.

Comment: If you wanted to make this more efficient you would skip the call to `ContainsKey` and just call `Add`. Detect duplicate when it raises an exception. That avoids two calls to `GetBucketIndex`. My instincts are that you'd need a huge array before this approach was actually faster than O(n log n) sort + search

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the moment the `TDictionary` based algorithm starts being faster depends on the average length of the strings within the array and the nature of the strings (example: do they share a long prefix that causes the compares in the sorting algorithm to take up more cycles?). See the revised answer.

Comment: +1 Very interesting indeed. I would not have thought that string length would play such a large role. That's because dictionary has to hash the entire string for all operations, but sorting and searching can short circuit. Did the GetBucketIndex optimisation prove to be an optimisation?

Comment: @David, yes it does, optimizing for `GetBucketIndex` plays a huge role: without it the string would be hashed twice, with your `try-except` suggestion it's only hashed once.

Answer (score 6):

Dynamic arrays don't need to be freed. They are managed types and the compiler makes sure that when there are no more references to the object, the object is destroyed.

As for detecting duplicates, you can do it like this:

```
function HasDuplicates(const arr: array of string): Boolean;
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(arr) do
    if arr[i]<>'' then
      for j := i+1 to high(arr) do
        if arr[i]=arr[j] then
          exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

I assume that when you say "null", in the context of a string you mean that the string is empty.

This is an algorithm with complexity O(n^2). That's bad news if the array is large.

If your array was ordered you can do the test with an O(n) algorithm.

```
function OrderedHasDuplicates(const arr: array of string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(arr)-1 do
    if arr[i]<>'' then
      if arr[i]=arr[i+1] then
        exit(True);
  Result := False;
end;
```

Naturally these functions can easily be modified to identify which index is the duplicate:

```
function IndexOfDuplicate(const arr: array of string): Integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for Result := 0 to high(arr) do
    if arr[Result]<>'' then
      for i := Result+1 to high(arr) do
        if arr[Result]=arr[i] then
          exit;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I get this question as *How to check if a certain element exists in the array twice ?*, not *Does a certain element exist in the array ?*. All the posts answer how to check for duplicates, but the bolded *twice* tries to say something else.

Comment: @TLama Clarification in comments suggests that Welliam is looking for duplicates

Answer (score 4):

To check whether a string exists twice, use the features of TStringList. Create a TStringList object, add all the elements (strings) of your array, set the Sorted property to True, then loop from the beginning to the end to check if the current element equals the last element, if its equal then you have found a duplicate.

The main advantage for using TStringList is the sorting functionality offered.

Comment: This makes no sense. You have the overhead of creating a new stringlist, a loop to copy the array into it, the overhead of sorting, and then another iteration to loop through looking at the content, and more than twice the memory used to create the stringlist and make a copy of tne entire array, all because the stringlist can be sorted? (Not downvoting, but seriously?)

Comment: If the original array is not sorted and large enough to make the in-place `O(n^2)` impractical then it needs to be sorted. If sorting in-place is not allowed then a copy needs to be made. Under those circumstances the proposed algorithm is OK: TStringList.Sort is implemented with QuickSort, a copy can't be avoided. Optimizing this corner-case would be fairly difficult!

Comment: Ken: I actually up-voted Steve's answer because the OP didn't mention anything about speed and memory requirements.  A solution using a TStringList is IMO the easiest and likely to be bugfree. I'm more likely to fail creating a bugfree solution in which I "roll my own" using loops, counters, high(), and subscript indexes as others have suggested.

A TStringList solution will almost definitely be easier to read, debug and maintain. And the code will likely to be self-documenting calls to TStringList.

Comment: @RobertFrank I would write this function once as a generic. So you only need to get it right once. And it would not need any maintenance since the rules of duplication will never change.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, @Robert: Don't need to write anything. `TArray<T>.Sort()`.

Comment: @CosminPrund That's very good, but I don't see duplicate finding in `TArray`. That's the bit I would write once. And I think you mean `TArray.Sort<T>`.

Comment: FWIW I also find the idea of firing up a `TStringList` for such a fundamental task rather distasteful. In my code I have a subclass that derives from `TArray` (the one in Generics.Collections) that adds lots of useful generic functions. Like `Swap<T>` on a pair of elements, `Reverse<T>`, `GetHashCode<T>`, `Copy<T>`, `Ordered<T>` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The TArray type is a classical dynamic array, in a Generics flavor. This type is managed by Delphi, so you don't need to manually free the memory involved. If you store objects or other dynamic created variable, you're still responsible to free that memory, but again, not the array itself.

Specifically on a TArray, being both managed types, you don't care about memory at all.

To check for duplicates in a non ordered array, you have to loop trough it and for each element, compare with the rest of the array, something in the lines of:

```
var
  arr: TArray<string>;
  e1, e2, e3, e4: string;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  e1 := 'val1';
  e2 := 'val2';
  e3 := 'val3';
  e4 := 'val4';

  arr := TArray<string>.Create(e1, e2, e3, e4);
  //check for duplicates
  for I := low(arr) to High(arr) do
    for J := I + 1 to High(arr) do
      if arr[I] = arr[J] then
        ShowMessage('A duplicate was found');
```

Finnally, a string cannot be null, so you don't have to check for null elements.

To be accurate, any empty string (`''`) is, in fact, a nil pointer, but that's the other side of the story.